# Django commands cron ImportError: cannot import name

Tags: django, django-models, django-commands

I want to add the models to the commands.
/home/max/askmoiseev/ask/management/commands/cron.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from ask.models import Tag


class Command(BaseCommand):

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        print args
```

$ python manage.py cron

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 272, in fetch_command
klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 75, in load_command_class
module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
__import__(name)
  File "/home/max/askmoiseev/ask/management/commands/cron.py", line 4, in <module>
from ask.models import Tag
  File "/home/max/askmoiseev/ask/models.py", line 3, in <module>
from loginsys.models import User
  File "/home/max/askmoiseev/loginsys/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
from ask.models import User
ImportError: cannot import name User
```

What's the problem?
I tried to do so:

```
#!/bin/bash
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=askmoiseev.settings
./manage.py cron
```

But it did not help.

Comment: You don't have a `User` class in `models.py` of the `ask` application.

Comment: @Burhan Khalid, yes, but I'm not requesting User in cron.py 
I've done it before. I do not know why is not updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below should work. You must make sure the Python/Django package askmoiseev is importable.
To make it importable the simplest way is to set your current working directory as the directory on which the package askmoiseev exists.

```
import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'askmoiseev.settings'
from ask.models import Tag
```

Comment: can make sure your current working directory is in the root of your Django project?

Comment: **max@Q210:~/askmoiseev$ ls**
ask  askmoiseev  cron.sh  loginsys  manage.py  scripts  static  templates  uploads
**max@Q210:~/askmoiseev$ python manage.py cron**
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv).........

Comment: run "from askmoiseev import settings" from your cwd. if it doesn't work then your problem is that the package askmoiseev is not visible to Python.

Comment: **max@Q210:~/askmoiseev$ from askmoiseev import settings**
from: can't read /var/mail/askmoiseev

Comment: @russianstudent can you run pwd?

Comment: **max@Q210:~/askmoiseev$ pwd**
/home/max/askmoiseev

Comment: @russianstudent "from askmoiseev import settings" this should be run from Python console. You ran it from the Bash shell.

Comment: all ok, **max@Q210:~/askmoiseev$ python**
Python 2.7.3 (default, Feb 27 2014, 20:00:17) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> **from askmoiseev import settings**
>>>

Comment: I do not know why, but now the error is not present, thanks for the help